# Grid of checkboxes represents a many-to-many db relationship; the best way to get from webform to database

Tags: java, jquery, data-structures

I am using jquery/jsp/java ejb3.0/sql server.

The User interface requirement (a jsp page) is a grid of checkboxes, ~10 rows high and up to about ~30 rows wide (this varies), it represents a linker table for a many-to-many table relationship.

The checkboxes will be populated from the database (if row present in linker table, then checkbox is checked).

The user can then check/uncheck whichever, as many times as possible. On submit any changes should be saved to db. 
The changes will consist of deleting a row if unchecked(and if checked/row present before), and inserting a row if checked (and unchecked/no row present before).

My problem is, what is the best way to implement this ? Using ajax to update database using checkbox onchange event is not appropriate. I want it to be a submit form event.

Comment: "30 rows wide" doesn't make sense. Do you mean ~10 rows high x ~30 columns wide? If so, do the items in each row/column have any relationship to each other or is the grid arrangement purely presentational?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try and decomplexify the situation by taking a step back and introducing a simple bean to represent the "metadata" - i.e. the 300-or-so true/false values.

Actually, when dealing with that many fields, you'd probably use a mother-bean containing child beans which hold conceptually-related fields together. e.g.:

```
public class MotherBean {
    private UserSettingBean userSettingBean;
    private UserRelationshipBean userRelationshipBean;
    private UserPreferencesBean userPreferencesBean;
    ...
}
```

So your "web tier" becomes a straightforward CRUD controller for the `MotherBean`; the sort of thing that gets done every day. You could even use something like [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo/why) to build up the scaffolding for that.

Then, when you pass that bean down into your lower layer(s) (you may or may not have a traditional "service" or "business logic" layer in this design), you have a DAO that translates the relationship metadata into the *actual* many-to-many relationships. Given the number of fields we're talking about, I'd again suggest to delegate out this work into sub-DAOs (for want of a better term) that deal with related links.

Obviously, the "get" path is the same thing in reverse. You ask the `MotherBeanDAO` for the metadata related to user 1234, it asks its delegate DAOs for the child beans, wraps them up and the resultant `MotherBean` gets passed all the way up to the web front end.